# Telebot - Проверка настроек пользователя (либо альтернатива)

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Столкнулся с такой проблемой.

Бот является сборщиком отзывов с возможностью ответных сообщений от админа.

Реализованы методы пересылки сообщений от пользователя к админу через бота, где админ, ответным сообщением на forward_message, заставляет бота переслать сообщение админа пользователю.

**В чем проблема:** Если имеется такая настройка пользователя: Пересылка сообщений - Никто / Кто может может ссылаться на мой аккаунт при пересылке сообщений - Никто, то бот не может взять из reply сообщения информацию от forward сообщения: reply.forward_from.id будет None, в таком случае и я обрабатываю это как "Аккаунт пользователя приватный" и человек не получит ответ в конечном счете, если он лично не изменит настройку в своем аккаунте.

Как можно решить проблему, чтобы в случае такой настройки админ мог отправить свой ответ?

**Что предпринимал:** Пытался сделать через добавление глобальной переменной usr_id, когда входил в метод пересылки сообщения от пользователя админу, но проблема возникает следующая: если придет два-три сообщения от разных людей с такой настройкой, то информация сохранится по последнему, т.е в случае отправки трех разных ответов на три разных отзыва мы сделаем отправку этих трех ответов одному человеку.
Думал над тем, чтобы создавать список из usr_id и обрабатывать его по мере использования - условно удалять, когда ответили, но в таком случае надо хранить абсолютно все сообщения с каким-то префиксом в виде Id пользователя и совершать постоянные проверки по этому массиву..

*Понимаю, что возможно для такой задачи реализация usr_id через список звучит более логичной, но хотелось бы узнать - есть ли какой-то иной вариант, более простой?*

Comment: Покажите ваш код.

Comment: github.com/MrAladawee/Telebot/blob/main/main.py - код.

Comment: Вставьте его в текст вопроса, никто не будет лазать по репозиториям.